# Insert and update at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem need to solve: I have 2 table in MySQL named Bata and Tranport.

For table Bata I have: id (PK, AI), phone, qty, price and grandtotal.

For table Tranport I have: id(PK, AI), phone, name, address and so on.

When the user clicks submit on Bata page the data will save into the database but the phone field will be left blank. When the user clicks submit on the Tranport page it will save data into database.

The question is how can I insert phone number from Tranport field into Bata phone field where the ID is the same? I have to do this because at the end user can review their order.

#### This is my code for transport

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', false);


$tranport = $_POST['Tranport'];
$name = $_POST['billName'];
$phone = $_POST['billPhone'];
$company = $_POST['billCompany'];
$address = $_POST['billAdd1']; 
$negeri = $_POST['negeri']; 
$label = $_POST['mylabel']; 
$date = $_POST['inputField'];

$input = "INSERT INTO tranport (deliverTyper , name , phone , company ,
   address , state    ,   rate , date )";

$input .= " VALUES ('$tranport', '$name', '$phone', '$company', '$address',
    '$negeri',   '    $label', '$date') "; 

require_once("connection.php");
mysqli_query($conn,$input);


$query = "INSERT INTO bata (phone) VALUES ('$phone')"; 

mysqli_query($conn,$query);


if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) <= 0)
{
print "Unable to create account.Please <a href='tranport.php'>click here</a>to try           gain.";
}
else
{
mysqli_close($conn);
header("Location:try.php?sebab=pengguna baru");
exit();
}

 mysqli_close($conn);


  ?>
```

Comment: This code has security problems, as @ExplosionPills has said. Do a search for "SQL injection", either here or on a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column of the last inserted entry using `mysqli_insert_id($conn)`.

---

Your code is vulnerable to injection.  You should use properly parameterized queries with PDO / mysqli

Comment: what do you mean vulnerable to injection??i add this to my code it insert to Bata table on phone field but it insert into new column not the existing id $id = mysqli_insert_id;

$query = "INSERT INTO bata ( phone) VALUES ( '$phone');"; 
   
mysqli_query($conn,$query);

Comment: @jaja you need to run the first `mysqli_query()` *before* `mysqli_insert_id`

Comment: i just can get it what do you mean..can you give full simple example to me please...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column of the last inserted entry using mysqli_insert_id($conn).

Here is the sample code for get last insert id

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "peter", "abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("test_db",$con);

$sql = "INSERT INTO person VALUES ('Børge','Refsnes','Sandnes','17')";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo "ID of last inserted record is: " . mysql_insert_id();

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: ok..then how to get value of phone inserted or update into field phone for bata table based on same id??